# JAX-WS Remove 'ns' prefix of xml tag

Tags: soap, jax-ws

How can I remove or rename 'ns2' prefix here:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:GetCatalogResponse xmlns:ns2="https://domain.com/">
         <GetCatalogResult>result</GetCatalogResult>
      </ns2:GetCatalogResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

package-info.java:

```
@XmlSchema(
    namespace = "https://domain.com/",
    xmlns = { 
        @XmlNs(prefix = "xxx", namespaceURI="https://domain.com/")
    },
    elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED
)
package com.domain.xxx;
```

Result:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:GetCatalogResponse xmlns:ns2="https://domain.com/">
         <GetCatalogResult>result</GetCatalogResult>
      </ns2:GetCatalogResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

By docs @XmlNs should override default prefix for xml items. But in my case it doesnt work.

Why?

Answer (score 2):

Prefix can be modified by `SOAPHandler` like this

```
SOAPEnvelope envelope = context.getMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
SOAPBody body = envelope.getBody();

Iterator iter = body.getChildElements();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Object object = iter.next();

    if (object instanceof SOAPElement) {
        SOAPElement element = (SOAPElement) object;
        element.removeNamespaceDeclaration(element.getPrefix());
        element.setPrefix("");
    }
}
```